# How do I remove plastic shelf brackets that have broken off in the hole?

Tags: shelving

A shelf fell from my bookcase.  It was supported by plastic brackets.  They broke off at the face of the side of the shelf.  How do I get them out so I can put new brackets in place?

Comment: We'll need a picture for this one... although if you mean they're adjustable shelves and plastic "L"-shaped brackets with a round peg that fits into one of a series of holes and the bracket broke off leaving the peg in place... you may be able to get it with a drywall screw or a straightened fishhook jammed right into the end of the peg.

Answer (score 7):

Plastic plug in a hole, I've always found drilling into it with a bit slightly smaller and stopping the drill, then pulling it straight out works dandy. If not, it gives to a place to try using a screw (and a nailpuller on the screw if it's REALLY stubborn) more easily. Then look for metal replacement brackets in the correct size for your bookshelf so it does not happen again.

[image]

Comment: Great advice. I had the best luck with this using the smallest drillbit I had. 1/16 worked pretty great.

Answer (score 2):

A dry wall screw with threads on it worked like a charm

Answer (score 0):

Previous answers should work, but if the broken pin spins in the hole without letting the screw grab hold, then a panelling nail could be the answer:

[image]

Also sometimes called ring-shank nails.  The ridges on the nail give it tremendous holding power.  Just drive in part way and pull out...

Answer (score 0):

Using the somewhat smaller diameter drywall screw did not work for me, but re-drilling the hole with the appropriate diameter drill did (ejecting the broken plastic bracket remnant in the process).

Answer (score 0):

I heated a screw tip and stuck it in the plastic and let it sit for a few seconds so that it would cool and then pulled it out.